# Simple js FOR loop returning 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, variables, for-loop

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here; the variable `newStr` should just return "Hello World", but I'm getting this instead:

```
"undefinedHello World"
undefined
```

JS

```
function translate2(x){
  var newStr;
  x = "Hello World";
  for(i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    newStr+=x.charAt(i);
  }
  console.log(newStr);
}
```

Comment: `var newStr = '';` `undefined + 'qwe'` === `'undefinedqwe'`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. In JavaScript, if a variable is not initialized explicitly, it will by default have [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/undefined). That is not a string but a primitive type of the Language. You can check that by printing it

   ```
   var newStr;
   console.log(newStr);
   // undefined
   console.log(newStr + "thefourtheye");
   // undefinedthefourtheye
   ```

   So, just initialize the variable with an empty string, like this

   ```
   var newStr = '';
   ```
2. Also, note that, in this line

   ```
   for(i=0; i < x.length; i++) {
   ```

   `i` has never been declared before. So, a new global variable `i` will be created. You may not want that. So, just use `var` keyword to declare the variable scoped to the current function, like this

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   ```
3. Apart from that, `translate2` is a function and when it is invoked, one would expect it to return something. But you are not returning anything explicitly. So, again, JavaScript, by default, returns `undefined`. That is why you are getting the second `undefined` in the question. To fix that, use `return` statement like this

   ```
   function translate2(x) {
       var newStr = "";
       for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
           newStr += x.charAt(i);
       }
       return newStr;
   }
   ```

Comment: Great, that worked. However, an additional undefined still remains in the console after the string is returned. Why would that be occurring?

Comment: @UncleSlug Did you try the third suggestion in my answer?

Comment: Yes, I used the 3rd suggestion.

Comment: @UncleSlug In the console, don't use `console.log(translate2(..))`, try simply `translate2(..)`. The `console.log` function call doesn't return anything, so `undefined` will be returned by default. That is why you are getting an extra `undefined` in the console.

Comment: in the console, I have been using just the function `translate2()`

Comment: @UncleSlug Okay, can you please show the current `translate2` function?

Comment: `function translate2(x){
  var newStr='';
  x = "Hello World";
  for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    newStr+=x.charAt(i);
  }
  console.log(newStr);
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71453/discussion-between-thefourtheye-and-uncle-slug).

Answer (score 3):

You should first initialize the variable newStr.

```
var newStr = '';
```

Otherwise, newStr will be undefined and undefined + "asa" = "undefinedasa" in javascript. If you don't know what is undefined, check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_undefined.asp) out.

Answer (score 0):

newStr is undefined.
Add

```
var newStr = '';
```

So that you have

```
function translate2(x){
    var newStr='';
    x = "Hello World";
    for(i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
        newStr+=x.charAt(i);
    }
    console.log(newStr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are not correct. The `console.log()` will run before the loop finishes and that is why you get `undefiend`.
You can find your answer [here](https://lavrton.com/javascript-loops-how-to-handle-async-await-6252dd3c795/).

you have to think sync like this piece of code:

```
function delay() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 300));
}

async function delayedLog(item) {
  // notice that we can await a function
  // that returns a promise
  await delay();
  console.log(item);
}
async function processArray(array) {
  for (const item of array) {
    await delayedLog(item);
  }
  console.log('Done!');
}
processArray([1, 2, 3]);
```

this will give you `1,2,3,done` which means the console.log is happening at the end of loop!

Comment: Fank You Abadis!