# why do I first get undefined in the console then it prints the numbers I want?

Tags: javascript

Why do I first get undefined in the console then it prints the numbers I want? How can I solve the code so that it does not write undefined in the beginning?

```js
var rangeStart;
var rangeStop;
var sum1;

function printRange(rangeStart, rangeStop) {
  for (rangeStart = 23; rangeStart < rangeStop; rangeStart++) {
    sum1 += rangeStart + ',';
  }
}

printRange(23, 47);
var sum1 = sum1.slice(0, -1);
console.log(sum1);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple js FOR loop returning 'undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665160/simple-js-for-loop-returning-undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var rangeStart;
var rangeStop;
var sum1;
```

Your first 3 variables declarations are unnessecary.
rangeStart and rangeStop don't need to be declared as they are gonna be arguments of yourfunction printRange.

sum1 , you declare it two times, the first time it initialize it to undefined, and then later, instead of assigning a value to an already declared variable, you redeclare it. That's why you have those 2 logs in the console.
The code below should do what you want to achieve.

```
function printRange(rangeStart, rangeStop) {
  let sum = ""; 
  for (var i = rangeStart; i < rangeStop; i++) {
    sum += i + ',';
  }
  return sum;
}

var sum1 = printRange(23, 47).slice(0, -1);
console.log(sum1);
```

Answer (score 2):

`sum1`'s value initially is `undefined`. Set it to `0` or `""` (empty string) first.

```js
var rangeStart;
var rangeStop;
var sum1 = 0; // here

function printRange(rangeStart, rangeStop) {
  for (rangeStart = 23; rangeStart < rangeStop; rangeStart++) {
    sum1 += rangeStart + ',';
  }
}

printRange(23, 47);
var sum1 = sum1.slice(0, -1);
console.log(sum1);
```

Comment: This will append `0` at start you need to handle in if case. to avoid `0` appending to string.

Comment: @aviboy2006 correct- its not clear what the OP wants, they called it `sum1` so that might be what is wanted.

Comment: you are right. Upvoting you to gave generalise answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you might want to use `let` instead of `var`, this method of declaring variables was introduced in ES6 - the latest version of JavaScript. Declaring variables with `let` improves the security of your code. [More info can be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var#:%7E:text=let%20allows%20you%20to%20declare,function%20regardless%20of%20block%20scope.)

To answer your question, you're declaring sum1 as '' (undefined) and afterwards you redeclare sum1 to be the product of sum1.slice(0,-1).

To fix the bug, try setting sum1 to 0 instead of ''.

```
let sum1 = 0
```

The console should then log the desired value.

Answer (score 1):

`sum1` is not defined (in `undefined` state). Try setting it to a empty string:

```js
    var rangeStart;
    var rangeStop;
    var sum1 = '';
    function printRange(rangeStart, rangeStop) {
     for (rangeStart = 23; rangeStart < rangeStop; rangeStart ++ ) {
         sum1 += rangeStart + ',';
     }
    }
    
    printRange(23,47);
    var sum1 = sum1.slice(0, -1);
    console.log(sum1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add if case for `undefined`. This error comes when you declared variable but used without defined initial values.

when `sum1 += rangeStart + ',';` sum1 doesnot have any value its `undefined`. This add in your string. To avoid you have to handle it separately.

```js
var rangeStart;
var rangeStop;
var sum1;

function printRange(rangeStart, rangeStop) {
  for (rangeStart = 23; rangeStart < rangeStop; rangeStart++) {
    if(sum1 == undefined){
    sum1 = rangeStart + ',';
    }
    else{ 
    sum1 += rangeStart + ',';
    }
  }
}

printRange(23, 47);
var sum1 = sum1.slice(0, -1);
console.log(sum1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix.. Try this...

```js
var rangeStart;
var rangeStop;
var sum1;

function printRange(rangeStart, rangeStop) {
    sum1="";     //added
  for (rangeStart = 23; rangeStart < rangeStop; rangeStart++) {
    sum1 += rangeStart + ',';
  }
}

printRange(23, 47);
var sum1 = sum1.slice(0, -1);
console.log(sum1);
```